# RangeError: The number ".." cannot be converted to a BigInt because it is not an integer

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing

pretty new to coding and solidiy - I'm testing a covered-call option smart contract in hardhat - specifically a function to refund the call writer if the option is not executed but I keep getting a range error.

here is my smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract CoveredCallContract {

    address public callWriter;
    address public callBuyer;
    uint public amount;
    uint public optionPrice;
    uint public strikePrice;
    uint public expiryDate;
    bool wasPurchased;

    constructor(uint _amount, uint _optionPrice, uint _strikePrice) {
        callWriter = msg.sender;
        amount = _amount;
        optionPrice = _optionPrice;
        strikePrice = _strikePrice;
        expiryDate = block.timestamp + 1 weeks;
    }

    // this function is how the callwriter deposits the collateral to cover the option
    function depositCollateral() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= amount, " Insufficient balance");
    }

    // this function allows the buyer to purchase the contract and pay the premium
    function purchaseOption() external payable {
        // ensure buyer hasn't already bought the option
        require(wasPurchased == false);
        // ensure buyer sends the correct amount
        require(msg.value == optionPrice, "Incorrect purchase price");
        // set the option buyer to the callbuyer
        callBuyer = msg.sender;
        // if the buyer buys the option, the price is transfered directly to the writer
        payable(callWriter).transfer(msg.value);
        // set the wasPurchased to true one the option has been purchased
        wasPurchased = true;

    }

    // the option will be executed if the price of ETH is above the strike price 
    function executeOption() external payable {
        // ensure the buyer has purchased the option
        require(wasPurchased == true);
        // make sure it's the buyer executing the contract
        require(msg.sender == callBuyer, "Unauthorized");
        // ensure the contract has been funded by the call writer
        require(address(this).balance == amount, "Funding error");
        // ensure the amount the buyer pays at execution is equal to the strikeprice
        require(msg.value == strikePrice, "Payment error");
        // make sure the contract has not expired
        require(block.timestamp <= expiryDate, "Option has already expired");
        // if all the above hold transfer the amount to the buyer
        payable(callBuyer).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    // if the option is not executed the initial funds will be sent back to the call writer
    function refund() public payable {
        if(wasPurchased == false) {
            require(block.timestamp >= expiryDate, "Option has not expired yet");
        }
        payable(callWriter).transfer((address(this).balance));
    }
}
```

here is my test in JS on the refund function:

```
it('should refund the writer if option not executed', async () => {
    const expiryDate = await coveredCallContract.expiryDate();
    const unixSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
    const oneWeek = 8 * 24 * 60 * 60;
    assert.equal(expiryDate, await hre.network.provider.request({
      method: "evm_setNextBlockTimestamp",
      params: [unixSeconds + oneWeek]
    }));
    await hre.network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine" });
    await coveredCallContract.refund({value: amount});
  });
```

Not quite sure how to make this work - any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know which line causes the problem? The only suspicious line seems to be `unixSeconds + oneWeek`, but I'm unsure if that line can cause that error. If you provide a complete minimal example we could check.

Comment: Hi! so it was intially line 66 and 70 as Date.Now() was a decimal and not in integer form. I used Math.round(Date.Now()/1000) to get around it however it's now throwing this error:

Comment: `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Option has not expired yet'`........at line 61 of the smartcontract code i.e. `require(block.timestamp >= expiryDate, "Option has not expired yet");`

Comment: this is the test now: `it('should refund the writer if option not executed', async () => {
    const expiryDate = await coveredCallContract.expiryDate();
    const unixSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
    const oneWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
    assert.isAtLeast(expiryDate, await hre.network.provider.request({
      method: "evm_setNextBlockTimestamp",
      params: [unixSeconds + oneWeek]
    }));
    await hre.network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine" });
    
    await coveredCallContract.refund({value: amount});
  });
})`

Comment: Please, edit the question when you want to add more details.